# Ssh remote command fails if private key is used for authentication instead of username/password

Tags: windows, authentication, ssh, openssh

I'm currently trying to execute a remote command on a windows server from a linux server via ssh.  The issue I'm having is that the behavior of the remote command seems to change based on how you logged in with ssh.  Windows is using OpenSSH.

If I ssh into the windows server utilizing a key, the remote command fails to authenticate.

Note that both of the following logins do successfully connect and allow me to log in to the server.  It's the command executing from the resulting prompt that's causing a problem.

**login via:** ssh USER@SERVER **-i IDENT_FILE** -c "command"

Output from command when executed from resulting prompt:

```
Information: 0 : Parsing [4] arguments that were provided to Certificate Installer Tool.
Information: 0 : Certificate will be linked to classic (CAPI) Cryptographic Services Provider...
Information: 0 :  Installer set to skip continue dialog. Running in unattended mode now...
Information: 0 : Installing certificate using Sign Operation Id: [XXX]
Information: 0 : Performing authorization...
Information: 0 : Contacting authorization server...
Information: 0 : Submitting authorization request...
Error: 0 : Unable to fecth access token. Status Code: Unauthorized
```

However, if I skip key authentication and enter the password at the prompt:

**login via:** ssh USER@SERVER -c "command"

Password entered at resulting prompt
Output from same command executed from resulting prompt:

```
Information: 0 : Parsing [4] arguments that were provided to Certificate Installer Tool.
Information: 0 : Certificate will be linked to classic (CAPI) Cryptographic Services Provider...
Information: 0 :  Installer set to skip continue dialog. Running in unattended mode now...
Information: 0 : Installing certificate using Sign Operation Id: [XXX]
Information: 0 : Performing authorization...
Information: 0 : Contacting authorization server...
Information: 0 : Submitting authorization request...
Information: 0 : Checking authorization response...
Information: 0 : Authorization succeded!
```

Why would the remote command behave different depending on if you are ssh'd in via a private key as opposed to username/password authentication?

Comment: Increase the verbosity with -v to a higher level in order to debug what is happening.  ssh servers can be configured to only accept a certain kind of authentication. Only password or public key auth or both, only if not root and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine's own id_rsa.pub key needs adding to the remote machine's authorized_keys file.

If you don't have one, you'll need to run ssh_keygen (OpenSSH) and add the generated public key to the remote machine under the user you wish to authenticate as.

It belongs as a line in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on Linux which you may already know - but I'm unsure of the whereabouts on Windows Server.

Edit: [seems this is not a new issue](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/openssh-password-vs-rsa-authentication-different-behaviour-on-windows-655128/), my guess would be Group policy on the Windows machine, or maybe you need to elevate and sudo the command?

Comment: Checking the keys file, the public key is there.  If it weren't, I wouldn't be able to log in at all, correct?  The problem is that while both methods do allow me to log in to the remote windows server, foo.exe executed from the two resulting prompts behaves differently.

Comment: edited original with some extra lines - wait til login then run the "command" - if no joy, sudo "command" or sudo su && "command"

Comment: Good find on that old post.  Unfortunately running as root or sudo doesn't seem to make any difference.  I've been at this over multiple days and haven't found any kind of resolution.  I think I'll shelf this for a bit and see if I can accomplish something productive in the meantime.

Comment: Just as a followup I could not resolve the issue.  I instead had to find a workaround that did not involve ssh.